# How to align text to left and output to right, in manipulate?

Tags: plotting, manipulate, output-formatting, text, version-7

I need to show a layer of information on a 3D graphics, inside a manipulate box.  Currently, all the code is working great, except that the text should be aligned to the left, while the output numbers should be aligned to the right (with a small spacing between text and the numbers).  Here's a MWE to show my problem, and a preview picture :

```
Info := Text[Row[{
    "Initial velocity :\t\t\t\t\t", NumberForm[0.678889, {12, 3}], "\[ScriptC]\n",
    "Final drift velocity :\t\t\t", NumberForm[0.567892, {12, 3}], "\[ScriptC]\n",
    "Final velocity :\t", NumberForm[0.5467899, {12, 3}], "\[ScriptC]\n",
    "Final adiabatic velocity :\t", NumberForm[0.2135467, {12, 3}], "\[ScriptC]\n",
    "Relative deviation of velocity :\t", NumberForm[112.6732145, {3, 1}], "%\n",
    "Ratio of radii :\t", NumberForm[237.9867, {3, 1}]
}, BaseStyle -> {FontSize -> 14, FontFamily -> "Courier", TextAlignment -> Left}],
{0.3, 0.075}]

ParametricPlot3D[{Sin[6 t], Cos[12 t], Sin[3 t]}, {t, -10, 10},
    PlotRange -> {{-2, 2}, {-2, 2}, {-2, 2}},
    Boxed -> True,
    Axes -> True,
    AxesOrigin -> {0, 0, 0},
    Epilog -> Info,
    SphericalRegion -> True,
    ImageSize -> {700, 700}]
```

Preview :

[image: text and numbers]

Currently, using several tabs (\t) doesn't work very well.

So how can I align all the text lines to the left, and align all the numbers to the right? (or even align numbers on their point separator, if possible?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could define `Info` like this:

```
Info := Inset[
  Grid[{{"Initial velocity : ", 
     NumberForm[0.678889, {12, 3}], 
     "\[ScriptC]"}, {"Final drift velocity : ", 
     NumberForm[0.567892, {12, 3}], 
     "\[ScriptC]"}, {"Final velocity : ", 
     NumberForm[0.5467899, {12, 3}], 
     "\[ScriptC]"}, {"Final adiabatic velocity : ", 
     NumberForm[0.2135467, {12, 3}], 
     "\[ScriptC]"}, {"Relative deviation of velocity : ", 
     NumberForm[112.6732145, {3, 1}], "%"}, {"Ratio of radii : ", 
     NumberForm[237.9867, {3, 1}]}}, 
   BaseStyle -> {FontSize -> 14, FontFamily -> "Courier"}, 
   Alignment -> Left], {0.3, 0.075}]
```

Comment: Appears to work very well.  I'll study this...

Comment: This solution is doing exactly what I was asking.  Thanks a lot !  I'm very tempted to mark it immediately as "THE" solution.  Just a question before :  what controls the spacing after the numbers, just before their units ?  What if I prefer a smaller spacing for the units only ?

Comment: See the `ItemSize` option for `Grid`. Also using `Frame->All` to see the grid cells.

Comment: Wow !  The Frame->All option is nice, as a table in the 3D view !

Comment: You could also put the 2nd & 3rd column together with `Row`, inside the grid.

Comment: Yep, works great !  I think this is it.  I'll wait a bit before marking your answer, in case someone else find something simpler (I doubt it !).  We never know, with Mathematica !

Comment: I suppose that to align by decimal point one could separate the numbers into their integer and decimal components and put them in two columns. It seems somewhat clumsy but that would be the complete answer, no?

Comment: @NicholasG You can just use `Alignment -> {{Left, "."}}`

Comment: @ChrisDegnen Thanks. `Alignment->"."` works for the numbers column but the rest of the table is right-aligned. `Alignment->{Left,"."}` does not work, nor does it if I add one more `Left` for the third column. The entire table is aligned left, I think. What works is to use the alternating pattern, `->{{Left,"."}}`.